# Delete Multidimensional Array Item By Values In the Item

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [id] => 2
    [name] => sallate me gjera plot 
    [price] => 8
    [category_id] => 25
    [dish_name] => sallate me gjera plot 
    [dish_id] => 2
    [dish_category_id] => 25
    [dish_qty] => 1
    [dish_price] => 8
)
Array
(
    [qty] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [name] => sallate cezar
    [price] => 12
    [category_id] => 25
    [dish_name] => sallate cezar
    [dish_id] => 1
    [dish_category_id] => 25
    [dish_qty] => 1
    [dish_price] => 12
)
```

And what I'm trying to do is to unset the item by dish_id.
This is the way I intend to do that :

```
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0)
        { 
            foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $key =>$cart_itm)
            {   
                if($cart_itm["dish_id"]==$removable_id)
                {
                    unset($cart_itm[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing worng..thanks :D

Comment: change `unset($cart_itm[$key]);` to `unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$key])` and check

Comment: That was it thanks alot :D

Comment: sorry @Anant first day here..I'm getting used to this :/

Comment: Sorry for my wordings if it hurts you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to `unset` data from actual array which is `$_SESSION["cart_products"]` not `$cart_itm`.

So change  `unset($cart_itm[$key]);` to `unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$key])`

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with an anonimous function:

```
$removable_id = 1;

$_SESSION["cart_products"] = array_filter
( 
    $_SESSION["cart_products"], 
    function( $row ) use( $removable_id )
    {
        return $row['dish_id'] != $removable_id; 
    }
);

print_r( $_SESSION["cart_products"] );
```

will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 1
            [id] => 2
            [name] => sallate me gjera plot 
            [price] => 8
            [category_id] => 25
            [dish_name] => sallate me gjera plot 
            [dish_id] => 2
            [dish_category_id] => 25
            [dish_qty] => 1
            [dish_price] => 8
        )

)
```